# Where to get images for pygame?

Tags: pygame

Hi I'm brand new to programming and I'm trying to program a sight reading app using pygame. I'm on a mac. I just need somewhere where I can download or create and save images onto my computer that can be manipulated using pygame. I've spent 3 days so far just trying to get something that resembles a note or bars that I can save in a file and load into a pygame window without success. I tried drawing it out on gimp, downloading premade stuff online (which my computer cant open for some reason even though its downloaded in files in my finder), and using a few different applications that have to do with creating sheet music. Basically my problem is that I have no idea how all the different types of files work and my computer just doesn't even open 99% of what I download or save, it just opens up an app, "File into Professional" and then gives me a window with a bunch of gibberish and apparently that has to do with the file I'm trying to open. Any advice is appreciated, obviously I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is too unspecific and therefore off-topic. It doesn't even look like a programming problem and I'm not sure what your actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

When opening a 'image file' (.jpg,.png,etc) with some program, and it ends up opening with gibberish, that means that that file type is not supported by that program and it just defaulted to opening the binary of the file.

When opening image files (I'm assuming that is what you are using for your assets), you can just use the default 'photos' app. You can right click and select 'open with' if double click is not opening with photos.

I would suggest saving your gimp images as .png files (remember you need to export as .png or save as .png, not just rename the files after saving them).

What types (in terms of file extensions) are you trying to open and having difficulty?

Comment: I figured out how to save my gimp files as .png, I had to "export" them instead of "save" them. Thanks for the advice.   Right now I can draw out (1-4) grand staffs in the pygame window and input any notes onto the top staff (right hand). All I have to do is input which type of note (8th-whole), which note, and which measure(1-6), and it places the note in the correct position. Now all I have to do to place notes on the rest of the staffs is write out functions that change the y coordinates for the note images based on which staff I input which will be 1-4 right hand or left hand (1R/L, 4R/L).

Comment: sounds like your on the right track, best of luck !